# Turning this addition code into subtraction

Tags: math-mode, macros, arithmetic

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xintexpr}[2018/05/18]% because we use randrange()

\newcommand{\BaseTenAddition}{%
% temporarily make definitions have global scope, because
% xint creation of variable is scope obedient and is lacking
% user interface for global scope (should be added in future)
\globaldefs1
%
% no need to reset \globaldefs afterwards explicitely
% as its setting will be extinguished after first cell...
%
  %% create 2 integer-valued random numbers, <1000
  \xintdefiivar num1 := randrange(1000);%
  \xintdefiivar num2 := randrange(1000);%
%
%
  %% Get base10 elements of num1 and num2
    \xintdefiivar num1_1    := num1 /: 10;% /: is modulo operator
    \xintdefiivar num1_10   := num1 /: 100 - num1_1;%
    \xintdefiivar num1_100  := num1 - num1_10 - num1_1;%
    \xintdefiivar num1_1000 := 0 ;%
    \xintdefiivar num2_1    := num2 /: 10;%
    \xintdefiivar num2_10   := num2 /: 100 - num2_1;%
    \xintdefiivar num2_100  := num2 - num2_10 - num2_1;%
    \xintdefiivar num2_1000 := 0 ;%
%
%
    %% show the two numbers and their base-10 reps
    &\xinttheiiexpr num1\relax
    &=&\xinttheiiexpr num1_1000\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num1_100\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num1_10\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num1_1\relax\\
    &\xinttheiiexpr num2\relax 
    &=&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1000\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_100\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_10\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1\relax\\
    \cmidrule(l){9-10}
    +\\ \addlinespace
%
%
    %% check if overflow in 1s column
\globaldefs1
    \xintdefiivar num2_1:=num1_1+num2_1;%
    \xintifbooliiexpr{num2_1 > 9}
      {\xintdefiivar num2_1 := num2_1-10;%
       \xintdefiivar carry := 10;%
       &\mbox{}&&&&&+&10\\
      }
      {\xintdefiivar carry := 0;}%
    &&&\xinttheiiexpr num1_1000\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num1_100\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num1_10\relax
    \\
    &&&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1000\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_100\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_10\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1\relax
    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
    +\\ \addlinespace 
%
%
    %% check if overflow in 10s column
\globaldefs1
    \xintdefiivar num2_10:=num1_10+num2_10+carry;%
    \xintifbooliiexpr{num2_10 > 90}
      {\xintdefiivar num2_10 := num2_10-100;%
       \xintdefiivar carry := 100;%
       &\mbox{}&&& + &100\\
      }
      {\xintdefiivar carry := 0;}%
    &&&\xinttheiiexpr num1_1000\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num1_100\relax\\
    &&&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1000\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_100\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_10\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1\relax\\
    \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
    +\\ \addlinespace
%
%
    %% check if overflow in 100s column
\globaldefs1
    \xintdefiivar num2_100:=num1_100+num2_100+carry;%
    \xintifbooliiexpr{num2_100 > 900}
      {\xintdefiivar num2_100 := num2_100-1000;%
       \xintdefiivar carry := 1000;%
       &\mbox{}&& 1000 \\
      }
      {\xintdefiivar carry := 0;}%
    \xintifbooliiexpr{carry>0}{&&&}{&&=&}%
    \xinttheiiexpr num2_1000\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_100\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_10\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1\relax
    \\
    \xintifbooliiexpr{carry > 0}
      {\cmidrule(lr){4-4}+\\}
      {\midrule}%
%
    %% print the final base-10 rep 
\globaldefs1
    \xintifbooliiexpr{carry>0}
      {\xintdefiivar num2_1000:=num2_1000+carry;%
        &&=&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1000\relax
         &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_100\relax
         &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_10\relax
         &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1\relax
         \\
         \midrule}
      {}% no false branch
%
%
    %% print the final result
    =&\xinttheiiexpr num1+num2\relax
}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{} % define width of 2nd col.

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{} l w{r}{\mylen} *{4}{cr} @{}}
  &&&1000\mbox{s}&\star& 100\mbox{s}&\star & 10\mbox{s}& \star &1\mbox{s}\\ 
  \midrule
  \BaseTenAddition  % the xintexpr-based macro does almost all the work
\end{array}
\]

Again
\[
\begin{array}{@{} l w{r}{\mylen} *{4}{cr} @{}}
  &&&1000\mbox{s}&\star& 100\mbox{s}&\star & 10\mbox{s}& \star &1\mbox{s}\\ 
  \midrule
  \BaseTenAddition  % the xintexpr-based macro does almost all the work
\end{array}
\]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

I am sorry for not making myself clear (as this question was taken down) but this is code to show addition using powers of ten, I would like it to do the same for subtraction. Do I need to re-code everything or can I just alter a few things, I know the array and random numbers work but I just know if I can change it from addition to subtraction.

Comment: Thank you for your help editing my question @ingmar, hopefully someone will now be able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change some `+` to `-`, some `-` to `+`, some `>9`, `>90`, `>900` to `< 0`, and add a few spaces to allow for a negative result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xintexpr}[2018/05/18]% because we use randrange()

\newcommand{\BaseTenAddition}{%
% temporarily make definitions have global scope, because
% xint creation of variable is scope obedient and is lacking
% user interface for global scope (should be added in future)
\globaldefs1
%
% no need to reset \globaldefs afterwards explicitely
% as its setting will be extinguished after first cell...
%
  %% create 2 integer-valued random numbers, <1000
  \xintdefiivar num1 := randrange(1000);%
  \xintdefiivar num2 := randrange(1000);%
%
%
  %% Get base10 elements of num1 and num2
    \xintdefiivar num1_1    := num1 /: 10;% /: is modulo operator
    \xintdefiivar num1_10   := num1 /: 100 - num1_1;%
    \xintdefiivar num1_100  := num1 - num1_10 - num1_1;%
    \xintdefiivar num1_1000 := 0 ;%
    \xintdefiivar num2_1    := num2 /: 10;%
    \xintdefiivar num2_10   := num2 /: 100 - num2_1;%
    \xintdefiivar num2_100  := num2 - num2_10 - num2_1;%
    \xintdefiivar num2_1000 := 0 ;%
%
%
    %% show the two numbers and their base-10 reps
    &\xinttheiiexpr num1\relax
    &=&\xinttheiiexpr num1_1000\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num1_100\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num1_10\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num1_1\relax\\
    &\xinttheiiexpr num2\relax 
    &=&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1000\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_100\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_10\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1\relax\\
    \cmidrule(l){9-10}
    -\\ \addlinespace
%
%
    %% check if overflow in 1s column
\globaldefs1
    \xintdefiivar num2_1:=num1_1-num2_1;%
    \xintifbooliiexpr{num2_1 < 0}
      {\xintdefiivar num2_1 := num2_1+10;%
       \xintdefiivar carry := -10;%
       &\mbox{}&&&&&-&10\\
      }
      {\xintdefiivar carry := 0;}%
    &&&\xinttheiiexpr num1_1000\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num1_100\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num1_10\relax
    \\
    &&&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1000\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_100\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_10\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1\relax
    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
    -\\ \addlinespace 
%
%
    %% check if overflow in 10s column
\globaldefs1
    \xintdefiivar num2_10:=num1_10-num2_10+carry;%
    \xintifbooliiexpr{num2_10 < 0}
      {\xintdefiivar num2_10 := num2_10+100;%
       \xintdefiivar carry := -100;%
       &\mbox{}&&& - &100\\
      }
      {\xintdefiivar carry := 0;}%
    &&&\xinttheiiexpr num1_1000\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num1_100\relax\\
    &&&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1000\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_100\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_10\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1\relax\\
    \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
    -\\ \addlinespace
%
%
    %% check if overflow in 100s column
\globaldefs1
    \xintdefiivar num2_100:=num1_100-num2_100+carry;%
    \xintifbooliiexpr{num2_100 < 0}
      {\xintdefiivar num2_100 := num2_100+1000;%
       \xintdefiivar carry := -1000;%
       &\mbox{}&& -1000 \\
      }
      {\xintdefiivar carry := 0;}%
    \xintifbooliiexpr{carry>0}{&&&}{&&=&}%
    \xinttheiiexpr num2_1000\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_100\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_10\relax
    &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1\relax
    \\
    \xintifbooliiexpr{carry > 0}
      {\cmidrule(lr){4-4}+\\}
      {\midrule}%
%
    %% print the final base-10 rep 
\globaldefs1
    \xintifbooliiexpr{carry>0}
      {\xintdefiivar num2_1000:=num2_1000+carry;%
        &&=&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1000\relax
         &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_100\relax
         &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_10\relax
         &+&\xinttheiiexpr num2_1\relax
         \\
         \midrule}
      {}% no false branch
%
%
    %% print the final result
    =~~~&\xinttheiiexpr num1-num2\relax
}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{} % define width of 2nd col.

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{} l w{r}{\mylen} *{4}{cr} @{}}
  &&&1000\mbox{s}&\star& 100\mbox{s}&\star & 10\mbox{s}& \star &1\mbox{s}\\ 
  \midrule
  \BaseTenAddition  % the xintexpr-based macro does almost all the work
\end{array}
\]

Again
\[
\begin{array}{@{} l w{r}{\mylen} *{4}{cr} @{}}
  &&&1000\mbox{s}&\star& 100\mbox{s}&\star & 10\mbox{s}& \star &1\mbox{s}\\ 
  \midrule
  \BaseTenAddition  % the xintexpr-based macro does almost all the work
\end{array}
\]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot your saved my day.